# Edit all files in a directory and save as another copy

Tags: bash, terminal, edit

I have 4 files in a directory "dir" called "a.txt", "b.txt" and "c.txt". All the files contain text.

a.txt:
The Chan Chan Man was arrested.

b.txt:
Chandler Bing got arrested.

c.txt:
Joey, duck and chick protested against the Chandler's arrest.

I want to delete specific keywords from all the files and store these new files in another directory "dir2". Lets say I want to delete "arrest" and "arrested". So new files become:

aNew.txt:
The Chan Chan Man was .

bNew.txt:
Chandler Bing got .

cNew.txt:
Joey, duck and chick protested against the Chandler's .

I am using Mac Terminal. It would be great if some one can give a solution for general case where files could in subdirectories and I could provide list of regular expression instead of keywords to delete.

Comment: Sample contents of files and how you wish to modify before saving will be useful in answering your question.

Comment: Made the edit. Added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

source=dir
dest=dir2

for file in a.txt b.txt c.txt
do
   # Copy the file to the destination directory
   cp "$source/$file" "$dest"

   # Modify the contents of the file in the destination directory.
   sed -i 's/arrested\././' "$dest/$file"
   sed -i 's/arrest\././' "$dest/$file"
done
```